# How to get TLS versions supporting any given cipher suite?

Tags: ssl, encryption, java-8, encryption-symmetric

I am working on securing the connection using cipher suite (in my case its - TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA).

On ssl socket I would like to explicitely enable all those TLS versions, which would support the cipher suite under consideration.

I am unable to find any mapping between TLS version vs Supported Cipher suite.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The suites are defined together with the various SSL/TLS versions. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) provides you with a good overview and with links to all necessary standards.

In your case: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA is defined for SSL3.0 already.

Comment: As per the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Key_exchange_or_key_agreement) PSK are not supported in SSLs, but only TLSs versions. Again not all PSK ciphers are supported in all TLS versions. e.g. PSK/AES/GCM is supported only in TLSv1.2. I am looking for some reay-made list or a way to find exactly.

Comment: `openssl ciphers -V` gives you a list of ciphers including the SSL/TLS version they belong too. And there you find your PSK cipher for SSLv3.